# Calling a function of RPostgreSQL in R

Tags: r, function, call, rpostgresql

I am quite new in R. I am using `RPostgreSQL` and I would like to utilize a code to automatically write new tables to the DataBAse. I am using this code, but I don't know how I could call it.

```
ndatatwrit <- list(n25,n28,n29,n31,n32)
lapply (ndatatwrit, function(i) {dbWriteTable (con,"i",ndatatwrit[[i]],overwrit)})
```

where `n25`,`n28`,`n29`,`n31`,`n32` are new tables.